# how does merkle root building work for empty array?

Tags: bitcoin-core, transactions, bitcoind, client

It's known that even if no transactions get created, bitcoin still creates a block with empty array of transactions.

In this way, I am curious what the merkle root would be. How does bitcoin figure out merkle root for empty array ? if there're even 1 transaction in it, I understand completely what it does, but what about empty array ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This cannot happen. Every block contains at least a "coinbase" transaction that distributes the subsidy and fees to the block's miners.

Blocks without coinbase are invalid, even if the subsidy were 0.